# convex function of n convex function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume $f$ is convex function that takes $n$ arguments, and we know $f$ is non-decreasing in every component.
Assume we have another $n$ convex functions: $h_1,...,h_n$
Does that composition $f(h_1(x_1),\ldots,h_n(x_n))$ is convex?

I assume it does, but I also know that the composition of convex function isn't necessarily convex so I'm having hard time to prove it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean for $f$ to be non-decreasing? How do you compare, for instance $f(2,1)$ with $f(1,2)$?

Comment: for every argument `f` is non-decreasing. i.e. x > y => f(x) >= f(y)

Comment: Just write the inequation for convexity

Comment: @RanEldan That definition of non-decreasing is only for univariate functions. Do you mean to say that $f$ is non-decreasing in each component?

Comment: Yes. This is my intention.

Comment: Hint:   Assume $\{x,y\}\subset R^n$.  Let $\alpha\in[0,1]$.  Let $z=\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y$.  Then is $h_k(z_k) \geq \alpha h_k(x_k) + (1-\alpha) h_k(y_k)$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots, n$?

Comment: Section 3.2.4 of https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha\in]0,1[$ and let $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ be in $\mathbb{R}^N$. To show convexity of your function, it suffices to show

\begin{equation}
f\left(h_1(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)y_1), \ldots, h_n(\alpha x_n + (1-\alpha) y_n)\right)\leq \alpha f(h_1(x_1),\ldots,h_n(x_n)) + (1-\alpha)f(h_1(y_1),\ldots,h_n(y_n)).
\end{equation}

**Proof idea**: For every $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, since $h_i$ is convex, we know
\begin{equation}
h_i(\alpha x_i + (1-\alpha) y_i)\leq \alpha h_i(x_i) + (1-\alpha)h_i(y_i).
\end{equation} Since we know $f$ is increasing in each component, we use this inequality in every component to find

\begin{equation}
f\left(h_1(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)y_1), \ldots, h_n(\alpha x_n + (1-\alpha) y_n)\right)\leq
f(\alpha h_1(x_1)+ (1-\alpha)h_1(y_1), \ldots, \alpha h_n(x_n) + (1-\alpha)h_n(y_n)).
\end{equation}

Notice that the righthand side above is just $f$ evaluated at $\alpha (h_i(x_i))_{1\leq i\leq n} + (1-\alpha) (h_i(y_i))_{1\leq i\leq n}.$ Using convexity of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will yield the desired inequality :)